# What is the significance of seaQuest's registry designation (DSV 4600)?

Tags: seaquest

seaQuest's [registry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SeaQuest_DSV_4600) / [hull number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hull_number) is **DSV 4600**.

Typically, hull numbers are sequential (there are indeed exceptions, but this is generally true). In the show, the first seaQuest (destroyed at the end of season 1) is designated "DSV 4600", while the second vessel (seasons 2 and 3) is designated [DSV 4600-II](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SeaQuest_DSV_4600#seaQuest_DSV_4600-II_3).

While DSV stands for "[deep submergence vehicle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_Submergence_Vehicle)", **what is the significance of 4600**?

Comment: I get the feeling few people even remember seaQuest.

Comment: I do, it was a favorite for the time. I just don't remember that much about it... I've been meaning to re-watch it on Netflix sometime, especially with the recent influx of questions on it...

Comment: I've rewatched the first season so far on Netflix.  I'd almost forgotten how truly epic and awesome the show was.  That, and they were all about saving the planet long before Al Gore came around.

Comment: @BBlake watch out for the later seasons. It started epic and went imho downwards. But with its ecological and social criticism it was ahead of its time.

Answer (score 8):

I asked my good friend, Rockne S. O'Bannon this question. The '*4600*' was apparently a nod to Amblin's studio building at the Universal lot in California.

---

> **Q.** *What did the '4600' stand for in 'seaQuest DSV 4600'?*
>
> **Rockne S. O'Bannon:** *4600 was the Building # for the Amblin bldg on the Universal lot.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Via Twitter](https://www.twitter.com/Rockne_S/status/790739440230510592)</sup></sub>

Comment: For the record, I believe he may have meant their telephone number since their address was *100 Universal Plaza Universal City, California 91608 U.S.A.. Telephone: (818) 777-**4600***. But then again, the telno may reflect the building number.

Answer (score 0):

I remember the show and at the time thought DSV referred to DSRV - a US Navy designation. The DSRV's were capable of depths to 1500 meters, or 5000 feet. I thought 4600 referred to the depth capabilities in meters -- about 15,000 feet of the majority of the ocean floor.

Comment: According to Wikipedia, seaQuest's crush depth is nearly 30,000 feet (9km). Further, given that the crush depths of most currently-active military submarines are confidential, it's doubtful that sQ's crush depth would be so obviously available.

Answer (score -2):

4600 might be just the hull number.  Military vessels, as well as civilian ships use them.

Comment: This answer could use some fleshing out.  Add more context for what hull numbers are, and maybe confirm that 4600 is a reasonable number for the SeaQuest.